# Can we create batch with Kafka by period?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Assume we have one topic with many partitions with each partition having key "id". Those consumers subscribed to specific "id" will get the message.

Besides having multiple partitions, we would also like to create batch in each partition based on given frequency. Each "id" (partition) will have its own frequency configuration (e.g. ID1 will have frequency of 5 mins, ID2 will have frequency of 10 mins). When ID1 has frequency of 5 mins, it means we will be creating batch of messages every 5 mins and send to consumer.

Is frequency configuration possible in Kafka? I have seen configuration that supports maximum number of messages per batch but not frequency. Please enlighten me.

Comment: Producer config `batch.size` refers to request payload **bytes**, not number of messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds more like `windowing` algorithm which is not implemented by classic `KafkaConsumer`. See if Kafka Streams would solve your request: https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/kafka-streams/windowing/